# Error converting JDBCConnection to OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, jdbc, jboss

I have a piece of code which is failing when running a stored procedure in Jboss7.1.0EAP in my spring-mvc project which is connecting to Oracle11g non-RAC.
I have used ojdbc14.jar in JBoss standalone

```
protected ARRAY registerOracleArray(String typeName, Connection connection,
  Object[] object) throws SQLException {
 System.out.println("Entered here");
 OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
  if (connection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
  oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
  }
 String inTypeName = "TBCAM." + typeName.toUpperCase();
 ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
   inTypeName, oracleConnection);
 return new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, oracleConnection, object);
}
```

Error coming in the logs:

> Error Message :- java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isWrapperFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Comment: Can you share more information? A bigger stacktrace would be better.

Comment: Yeah..I am trying to get more

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using? The error suggests you are using a variant for Java 5 or earlier (eg ojdbc14, which is for Java 1.4).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using ojdbc14 driver which is to old.
Get a more recent one e.g. here https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html.

Don't get irritated by the 14 in ojdbc14 it is not newer than ojdbc6 or ojdbc7. The number is referring the java version (so 14 means 1.4).

Comment: By Using Ojdbc7.jar and getting the connection manually I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

•   There was compatibility issue with oracle jar used.
•   Also database connection object returned from JBOSS7 datasource pooling is of type  org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8. This is not the expected object and casting this to Oracle connection object is throwing an error.

Solutions Applied : 
•   Upgraded the jars to Oracle7 using ojdbc7.jar
•   Instead of getting database connection from JBOSS pool, created the connection from JDBC.

Comment: I guess you could still use the connection from the pool and call WrappedConnectionJDK8.getUnderlyingConnection()